# Fill nested arrays in a dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with this structure:

```
 |-- col0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

The array column has to save two elements (arrays), created from the element is not missing.
As an example, I have this:

```
|0.0 |[[0.0, 182.0], [1.0, 14.0]]|
|0.0 |[[1.0, 60.0]]              |
|1.0 |[[0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 48.0]]  |
|2.0 |[[1.0, 6.0], [0.0, 111.0]] |
|0.0 |[[1.0, 4.0], [0.0, 120.0]] |
|2.0 |[[0.0, 21.0]]              |
|0.0 |[[0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 13.0]]  |
```

And the desired result is:

```
|0.0 |[[0.0, 182.0], [1.0, 14.0]]|
|0.0 |[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 60.0]]  |
|1.0 |[[0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 48.0]]  |
|2.0 |[[0.0, 111.0], [1.0, 6.0]] |
|0.0 |[[0.0, 120.0], [1.0, 4.0]] |
|2.0 |[[0.0, 21.0], [1.0, 0.0]]  |
|0.0 |[[0.0, 3.0], [1.0, 13.0]]  |
```

So, when the array has 2 elements, nothing to do. But if it has one element, I need to create a second element with the value that is missing (if has an element with value 0.0, I need to create one with value [1.0, 0.0], and if has an element with value 0.0, I need [0.0, 0.0]).

I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
val headValue = udf((arr: Array[Array[Double]], maxValue: Double, minValue: Double) => {
  val flatArr = arr.flatMap(_.headOption)
  val nArr = arr
  if (flatArr.length == 1){
    if (flatArr.head == maxValue){
      nArr :+  Array (minValue, 0.0)
    } else {
      nArr :+  Array (maxValue, 0.0)
    }
  } else {
    nArr
  }
})

df.withColumn("Test", headValue(df("arrOfarr"), lit(maxValue), lit(minValue) ))
```

And the error is:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$20: (array<array<double>>, double, double) => array<array<double>>)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [[D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining input to UDF as `Array`, define it as `Seq` and you should be good:

```
val headValue = udf((arr: Seq[Seq[Double]], maxValue: Double, minValue: Double) => {
  val flatArr = arr.flatMap(_.headOption)
  val nArr = arr
  if (flatArr.length == 1){
    if (flatArr.head == maxValue){
      nArr :+  Seq(minValue, 0.0)
    } else {
      nArr :+  Seq(maxValue, 0.0)
    }
  } else {
    nArr
  }
})
```